# Error in DeserializeObject method json?

Tags: asp.net, json

I have class in my project:

```
public class ProductType
{
    private string name;
    private Guid id;        

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public Guid Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public ProductType(string Name)
    {
        id = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.name = Name;
    }               

    public ProductType(Guid Id, string Name)
    {
        this.id = Id;
        this.name = Name;
    }       
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize a json object of this class like the following

```
strObjJson = "{\"Name\":\"proName\"}";
```

using this:

```
ProductType deserializedProductType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strObjJson);
```

However the following error appears:

```
Unable to find a constructor to use for type `ClassLibraryObjects.ProductType`. A class should either have a default constructor or only one constructor with arguments.
```

How can I repair this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if the error says:

> Unable to find a constructor to use
>   for type
>   ClassLibraryObjects.ProductType. A
>   class should either have a default
>   constructor or only one constructor
>   with arguments.

Then why don't you add a constructor with no arguments?

```
public ProductType()
{
}
```

Comment: I'am impressed) It,s helped. But I think that I already have the necessary method with one argument: ProductType(string Name)( id = Guid.NewGuid();this.name = Name;)  and it won't work.

Comment: The error message says "have a default constructor" - that means no arguments.

Comment: The error also says "or only one constructor with arguments".  So if you don't need both of those constructors then delete one of `ProductType(string Name)` or `ProductType(Guid Id, string Name)`

Answer (score 1):

What the exception means is that - You have 2 ctors that each take varied number of args. You also don't have a public ctor which doesn't take parameters.

I noticed that you were expecting Guid to be passed by the caller? which I don't think is necessary.
You could modify the code by removing the below ctor (1) and adding a new one (2)

```
        // (1) remove this from your code
        public ProductType(string Name)
        {
            id = Guid.NewGuid();
            this.name = Name;
        }

        // (2) add this ctor 
        public ProductType(string Name, Guid id = default(Guid))
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = Name;
        }
```

This should do the trick.
PS: I tried the code with `JavaScriptSerializer` from `System.Web.Extensions.dll`